# Magento2: Can we add navigation layered filter like price filter for other attribute?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, multiselect-attribute

I want to add navigation layered a filter like a price filter for custom attribute:

**Attribute name size:**

```
10 above
10 - 20 inch
20 - 30 inch
30 - 40 inch
40 - 50 inch
Under 50 inch
```

Anyone can tell me It is possible on a custom attribute?

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question correctly. But you can create custom attribute in admin and then use them in filter area. If that is what you are asking for.

Comment: I want to add from - to and ranger slider like price attribute on the length.  @k185

Comment: you can use this extension ElasticSuite extension: https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite adds possibility to create numeric attributes, and filter them using sliders in layered navigation.

Comment: Ok, I will check and update you. Thanks! @RakeshDonga